# HttpRuntime..cctor takes forever to execute

Tags: c#, httpruntime, typeinitializer

Dead simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Caching;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Cache cache = HttpRuntime.Cache;
            Console.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

And I've already been waiting for output for over 5 minutes. This problem started to manifest itself about a week ago (may be less) and three more computers (my coworkers' boxes) experience the same behavior, except that some of them manage to initialize `HttpRuntime` in under a minute, which is still very weird.

Has anybody experienced that? And what do I do with it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd use some of the [SysInternals tools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/0e18b180-9b7a-4c49-8120-c47c5a693683.aspx) to work out what it's doing - whether it's trying to make network connections etc. Process Monitor will show you file and registry access; TCPView will show you what ports it's got open. (You might want to use [WireShark](http://wireshark.org) to monitor what it's doing too.)

Is this running locally, or on a UNC path?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Mark "SysInternals" Russinovich's blog](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/default.aspx) about possible approaches if simpler steps don't show anything. Interesting entries include "[The Case of the Delayed Windows Vista File Open Dialogs](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2006/11/27/532465.aspx)" and "[The Case of the Slooooow System](http://blogs.technet.com/markrussinovich/archive/2008/09/24/3126858.aspx)".